# Repeat sending the request to another server until the expected result is achieved

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm requesting to server "S" to get some data, but this data may not be ready.

When the data is not yet ready, server S responds with `{"data":null,"state": "pending"}` but when the data has been prepared the response will be something like `{"data": {...somedata}, "state": "done"}`.

I have to repeat the request until the data is ready. What I'm doing now is something like this:

```js
let wait = function* () {
  let t = 500;
  for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    yield new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), t*=2);
    });
  }
}();

let result = await sendRequestToS();
status = result;
for (let i = 0; i < 4 && result.state==='pending'; i++) {
  await wait.next().value;
  result = await sendRequestToS();
}
```

As you can see, I send the request up to 4 times with a delay of 1, 2, 4 and 8 seconds.

Am I doing this the right way?
Isn't that (using **setTimeout** to delay between requests) a **bad practice**?

Answer (score 1):

I'd write this as such:

```js
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

async function requestAndRetry() {

  let retries = 10;
  let timeout = 1000;

  while(retries>0) {

    const response = await sendRequestToS();
    if (result?.state === 'done') {
      return result;
    }

    await wait(timeout);
    retries--;
    timeout*=2;

  }

  throw new Error('Request failed after 10 retries');

}
```

I don't think it's a bad idea. It's called exponential back-off and you're not blocking the script engine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using generators directly, you could simply do this using `async/await` and recursion. Here's an example which tries to get the response a limited number of times in order to prevent an endless recursion and with a timeout between retries:

```
async function wait(timeInMs) {
  console.log('Waiting ...');
  return new Promise((resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeInMs)));
}


async function tryRequestToS(numberOfTries, timeout) {
  if (numberOfTries <= 0) {
     throw new Error("could net get result");
  }

  const result = await sendRequestToS();

  if (result && result.state === "done") {
    return result;
  }

  await wait(timeout); // wait for the defined timeout before recurring

  return tryRequestToS(numberOfTries - 1, timeout);
}

(async () => {
   try {
     const result = await tryRequestToS(10, 500); // max. 10 retries, 500 ms delay between retries
     console.log(result);
   } catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, but your code act just as mine (of course, the timeout must be multiplied by 2 each time).
My question is about using **setTimeout**, isn't that a bad solution?!

Comment: Does it have any advantage over that? @eol

Comment: Why use recursion at all? This could also just be a loop, no?

Comment: @Evert: Sure, why not? I just think it's one of the cases where recursion is elegant to use ..